# How can i put long text and image next to each other in td in table?

Tags: css, angular, sass

I have this code.I have one td where on the left is putted the user name image,and on the right his first name.The problem here is that if the first is too long that the image putted in the figure is disappeared.It works fine if the first name is maximum 10 characters

How can i solve this issue with css.Any suggestions please

```
 <div *ngIf="predictions.length" class="matches-tabs__content tab-content">
        <div class="match-lineups-container tab-pane fade show active" id="tab-1" role="tabpanel">
          <div class="table-responsive">
            <table class="matches-table lineups-table lineups-table--style-3 table table-striped table-dark">
              <tbody>
                <tr>
                  <th></th>           
                </tr>
                <tr *ngFor="let prediction of predictions; index as i;">

                  <td>
                    <a [routerLink]="['/user', prediction.created_by_user_id]">
                      <figure class="match-player team-1 figure" role="group">
                        <figure class="match-player__avatar">
                          <img src="assets/img/s\amples/match-player-01-60x60.png" alt="">
                        </figure>
                        <figcaption>
                          <span class="match-player__nickname">{{ prediction.created_by_user_alias }}</span>
                          <span class="match-player__name">{{ prediction.created_by_user_first_name + " " + prediction.created_by_user_last_name }}</span>
                        </figcaption>
                      </figure>
                    </a>
                  </td>
```

Answer (score 0):

If ending the name with '...' instead of showing all of it is a solution for you, you could put the text between a 'p' tag with a 'text-ellipsis' class like this:

```
<span class="match-player__name"><p class="text-ellipsis">{{ prediction.created_by_user_first_name + " " + prediction.created_by_user_last_name }}</p></span>
```

And define the class as follows:

```
.text-ellipsis {
    text-overflow: ellipsis;
    overflow: hidden;
    white-space: nowrap;
}
```